# How to load/save a nonlinear model in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, non-linear-regression

I've used fitnlm() in a loop to create a cell array of nonlinear models.
and saved said cell array
like this:

```
for i=1:N
    modelfun =  @(b,x)model_func_3(b,x,n);
    inital_b = rand((n+1)*(n+2)/2,2)
    model_array{i} = fitnlm(center_ptsSet(:),center_ptsRef(:),modelfun,inital_b);
end;
save('some_path.mat',model_array);
```

where model_func_3 is just a simple function and center_ptsSet,center_ptsRef are MX1 data sets
now when I want to load said cell array by dragging into MATLAB or by using load() its stuck on 'busy'

does anyone know why? or what I did wrong?

Comment: Perhaps its just big and take time to load.... The code you show should work. At the same time, this is not the code you are actually running, so who knows if there is a bug

Comment: 1. it's not that big ~9MB
2. you are right, I re-edited the code to look more like mine

Comment: There should not be any problem loading/saving any MATLAB type. If there is, either you are saving it wrong (e.h. with a typo in the extension) or your MATLAB is broken

Comment: the problem description is incomplete since we don't have the data and rest of code are used here.